# find an integral limits

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Let $f(x)$ a continuous function in $[-1, 1]$.

Prove that $$0 < \int_{-1}^{1}  \frac{dx}{1+(f(x))^2} \leq 2$$

How can I prove this? 
$$ (f(x))^2 \geq 0 \implies 1+ (f(x))^2 \geq 1 \implies 0 < \frac{1}{1+(f(x) )^2} \leq 1$$

How do I continue from here? is that possible to find a primitive function for this integral?

Comment: Just integrate your inequalities between $-1$ and $1$.

Comment: Hint: $f(x)$ is a continuous function in [-1,1], so it has maximum M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Integral is a monotone operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_integration#Basic_theorems_of_the_Lebesgue_integral) which means that if $f$ and $g$ are integrable function in $[a,b]$ and $f(x)\leq g(x)$ for $x\in[a,b]$ then
$$\int_a^bf(x)\,dx\leq \int_a^bg(x)\,dx.$$

Hence, in your case, since $f^2$ is continuous in $[-1,1]$ then it attains there a maximum value $M\geq 0$ and for any $x\in [a,b]$
$$0<\frac{1}{1+M}\leq\frac{1}{1+f^2(x)} \leq 1$$
which implies
$$0<\frac{2}{1+M}=\int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{1+M}dx \leq \int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{1+f^2(x)}\,dx \leq \int_{-1}^11dx=2.$$

Comment: I get what your saying and it's great but what it has to be greater than zero and not greater equal. how can I prove that?

Comment: @Dan Revah See my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

\begin{equation} 
\int_{-1}^{1}  \frac{dx}{1+(f(x))^2} \leq \int_{-1}^{1}  \frac{dx}{1+m^2}= \frac{1}{1+m^2}\int_{-1}^{1} dx=\frac{2}{1+m^2}\leq 2
\end{equation}

where $m$ is the minimum of $f$.

Answer (score 0):

Just as @Robert Z said, if $f,g,h$ are integrable function in $[a,b]$ and 
$$h(x)\le f(x) \le g(x),$$
then
$$\int_{a}^{b}{h(x)}d(x) \le \int_{a}^{b}{f(x)}d(x) \le \int_{a}^{b}{g(x)}d(x).$$

Let $h(x)=0$ and $g(x)=1$, combining with what you have got
$$0\le \frac{1}{1+(f(x))^2}\le 1,$$
you will have your answer.